# How to access the native android scrollview listener from nativescript angular?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Iam working android and ios application using nativescript application,I was created the customised scrollview with extending android.widget.ScrollView in nativescript angular and i had listeners inside the scrollview.I want to set my customised scrollview listeners and its override methods to the nativescript angular scrollview.How can i set this android customised listeners to scrollview like setting ios delegate methods?

My Customised scrollView java class is:

```
import android.content.Context;

public class AndScroll extends org.nativescript.widgets.VerticalScrollView
{
    public interface OnEndScrollListener {
        public void onEndScroll(int x,int y);
    }
    private boolean mIsFling;
    private OnEndScrollListener mOnEndScrollListener;

    public AndScroll(Context context)
    {
        super(context)
    }
    @Override
    public void fling(int velocityY) {
        super.fling(velocityY);
        mIsFling = true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY) {
        super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldX, oldY);
        if (mIsFling) {
            if (Math.abs(y - oldY) < 2 || y >= getMeasuredHeight() || y == 0) {
                if (mOnEndScrollListener != null) {
                    mOnEndScrollListener.onEndScroll(x,y);
                }
                mIsFling = false;
            }
        }
    }
    public OnEndScrollListener getOnEndScrollListener() {
        return mOnEndScrollListener;
    }

    public void setOnEndScrollListener(OnEndScrollListener mOnEndScrollListener) {
        this.mOnEndScrollListener = mOnEndScrollListener;
    }


}
```

Iam want to access my customised class inside my FoodCourt Scroll ts class:

```
public createNativeView() {
    return this.orientation === "horizontal" ? new org.nativescript.widgets.HorizontalScrollView(this._context) : new org.nativescript.widgets.VerticalScrollView(this._context);
}
```

How to access My AndScroll java class in my foodcourt class like

```
new org.nativescript.widgets.VerticalScrollView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [org.nativescript.widgets.VerticalScrollView](https://github.com/NativeScript/tns-core-modules-widgets/blob/master/android/widgets/src/main/java/org/nativescript/widgets/VerticalScrollView.java) if you like to preserve the features exposed by `ScrollView` component while modifying it.

If your aim is to just intercept `OnScrollChangedListener` then you just have to do it like it's done [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/scroll-view/scroll-view.android.ts#L127) in the original source code.

But I don't think you would actually need any of these, `scroll` event itself gives you the x & y points constantly if that's all you are looking for within `OnScrollChangedListener`.

Comment: Is VerticalScrollview widget is available in nativescript angular?

Comment: It's part of your NativeScript Framework. Angular is a wrapper around the Core Framework just to expose the features of Angular. So anything that's available in Core, should be available for framework.

Comment: Ok thank you manoj..and one more question i want to ask you is the verticalscrollview widget only for android?

Comment: Yes, it's Android specific native component, like `UIScrollView` on iOS.

Comment: Ok thank you manoj.i am going to try implement the verticalscrollview.

Comment: Hai manoj i was extends the VerticalScrollView like "export class AndScroll extends VerticalScrollView" but it shows error Cannot find name 'VerticalScrollView'.

Comment: The fully qualified class name is `org.nativescript.widgets.VerticalScrollView`. As I mentioned above, I don't actually see an requirement for extending when the `scroll` event itself gives you the x & y axis points you need to work with.

Comment: Ok..ios scrollview have the scroll end delegate method to detect scroll ends. but android don't have.so only i was saw an workaround to detect end scroll in android java code and i was converted the code into nativescript.But i dont know how to achieve in android like ios

Comment: I think with Android you may just listen to `scroll` event, set an interval - let's say 200 or 300ms, if the next event is not fired within that time frame you may assume the scroll ended.

Comment: Why i want to extend  org.nativescript.widgets.VerticalScrollView is "fling"  override method is depends on the native android scrollview.I will update my question please see.

Comment: I think you are pretty confused between the cross platform JavaScript component & native component. Whatever you use in XML are the cross platform JavaScript component that implements the native view within, for more info refer [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/ui-plugin-custom).

Comment: ok manoj.in the above mentioned code implementation was wrong?

Comment: I also tried setinterval inside the scroll event but it was slows the scroll speed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189209/discussion-between-arigarasuthan-and-manoj).

Comment: Hai manoj i have implemented like original implementation. i have one doubt how to access my AndScroll java class like they accessing "org.nativescript.widgets.VerticalScrollView"
I will update my question please check.

Comment: Any solution Manoj?